# Шаблонная factory функция

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename Arg>
std::shared_ptr<T> factory(const Arg& arg) {
    std::cout << "factory1\n";
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg)); 
}

template<typename T, typename Arg>
std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg&& arg) {
    std::cout << "factory2\n";
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::move(arg))); 
}

int main()
{
    auto sp1 = factory<std::string>(std::string("AAAAA"));
    std::string s("BBBBBBB");
    auto sp2 = factory<std::string>(s);
}
```

output:

```
factory2
factory2
```

Шаблонные функции взяты из примеров ю-туб лекции по с++11. Второй вызов factory должен был привести к вызову второй функции, то есть, в консоли ожидалось:

```
factory2
factory1
```

Почему всегда вызывается factory2? Как вызвать factory1?

Comment: А для чего два аргумента шаблона?... У вас практически  Arg   имеет  тип только T*

Comment: Это пример из лекции по с++11, он был использован для демонстрации применения std::forward, как и расписал ниже @HolyBlackCat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

У вас во второй функции параметр - не обычная rvalue-ссылка, а так называемая **пробрасывающая ссылка**<sup>1</sup>, которая одинаково хорошо обрабатывает и lvalue, и rvalue.

В этом случае она сработала как `std::string &`. А этот вариант подходит лучше, чем `const std::string &`, так что вызывается вторая функция.

<sup>1 — Англ. "forwarding reference", иногда еще переводят как "передаваемая ссылка". Менее распространено другое название, "universal reference" - универсальная ссылка.</sup>

---

**Что еще за пробрасывающие ссылки**

Их иногда называют "универсальными" - потому их одинаково хорошо можно инициализировать выражениями не только любого типа, но и любой категории: lvalue или rvalue. С информацией о категории дальше можно делать что угодно, но обычно ее используют, чтобы передать ("пробросить") ссылку куда-то еще с сохранением оригинальной категории. Такая передача называется perfect forwarding - "идеальная передача".

По сути, "пробрасывающая ссылка" - это rvalue-ссылка (`&&`), но не на любой тип, а на параметр шаблона, который при вызове функции вы позволили компилятору определить за вас. (Иначе особые свойства пробрасывющей ссылки пропадают, и она превращается в обычную rvalue-ссылку.)
Также, вместо параметра шаблона подходит `auto` - если ссылка является отдельной переменной или параметром лямбды. (В C++20 добавился краткий способ записи шаблонов функций, позволяющий использовать `auto` также в параметрах обычных функций.)

---

**Почему это работает**

Почему такая ссылка принимает и lvalue тоже, хотя, казалось бы, должна работать только с rvalue?

Сначала нужно рассказать про...

---

**Правила схлопывания ссылок**

Думаю понятно, что так писать нельзя: `int & &&` - ссылок на ссылки не бывает, компилятор запрещает их создавать.

Однако, что есть написать так?

```
using A = int &;
A &&my_reference = что-нибудь;
```

Этот вариант скомпилируется.

`my_reference` будет иметь тип `int &`. Почему? Из-за этих самых правил схлопывания ссылок.

Если вы пытаетесь создать ссылку на ссылку (не напрямую, ведь это ошибка, а через `using`и или параметры шаблонов), то вид ссылки, которая получится: на lvalue или на rvalue - определяется по этим правилам:

```
&  + &  -> &
&& + &  -> &
&  + && -> &
&& + && -> &&
```

Почему именно так? Понятия не имею; слышал, что эти правила специально подгоняли под пробрасывющие ссылки... Подробнее ниже.

---

**Определение аргумента шаблона по пробрасывющей ссылке**

Казалось бы, какой смысл в правилах схлопывания ссылок? Вот какой:

Если вы пытаетесь передать в пробрасывющую ссылку rvalue, то аргумент шаблона определяется компилятором по обычным правилам:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&) {}

foo(1); // T = int
```

С этим все понятно, и никаких вопросов не возникает.

Однако, если передать lvalue, вот так:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&) {}

foo(1); // T = int

int x = 1;
foo(x); // T = int &
```

То **шаблонный аргумент будет определен как lvalue-ссылка**. Далее, по правилам схлопывания ссылок весь параметр функции становится lvalue-ссылкой.

Если передавать константный объект, то тип будет определен, соответственно, как `const T` или `const T &`.

> Теперь должно быть понятно, почему в вашем случае оба раза вызывается вторая перегрузка.
>
> В этом примере:
>
> ```
> std::string s("BBBBBBB");
> factory<std::string>(s);
> ```
>
> Параметр функции, благодаря пробрасывающей ссылке, получит тип `std::string &`.
>
> А это более подходящий тип, чем `const std::string &`, так что выбирается вариант с пробрасывающей ссылкой.

---

**Как пользоваться пробрасывающими ссылками**

Все удобство в том, что теперь мы внутри шаблона можем определить, что нам передали - lvalue или rvalue. И на основе этого решить, например, делать `std::move` или нет.

Как именно определить? По тому, определился ли параметр шаблона как ссылка:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&)
{
    if (std::is_reference_v<T>) // Или is_lvalue_reference, без разницы.
        std::cout << "lvalue\n";
    else
        std::cout << "rvalue\n";
}
```

> Для справки: Можно подумать, что проверка на lvalue/rvalue -
> бесполезное занятие, и попробовать написать так:
>
> ```
> template <typename T, typename Arg> std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg &&arg)
> {
>     return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg)); 
> }
> ```
>
> Но это не сработает. Rvalue-ссылки, как и любые переменные, сами являются lvalue (хотя и *ссылаются на* rvalue), и к ним нужно применять `std::move`. Такой вот курьез языка.

Ладно, а как на основе этого сделать условный `std::move`? Наивный вариант выглядит так:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg> std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg &&arg)
{
    if (std::is_reference_v<T>)
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(arg)); 
    else
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::move(arg))); 
}
```

Однако, есть вариант проще. В стандартной библиотеке уже есть все необходимое:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg> std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg &&arg)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Arg>(arg))); 
}
```

`std::forward` - это, по сути, условный `std::move`. Если его шаблонный параметр - это lvalue ссылка, то он ничего не делает. А иначе он работает как `std::move`.

Если не нравится стандартная библиотека, можно даже так:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg> std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg &&arg)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T((Arg &&)arg)); 
}
```

Эффект точно такой же. Это работает из-за правил схлопывания ссылок, описанных выше.

---

**Итог**

Таким образом, вам не нужно две перегрузки.

Достаточно одной всеядной:

```
template <typename T, typename Arg> std::shared_ptr<T> factory(Arg &&arg)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Arg>(arg))); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`factory(Arg&& arg)` это «всеядный» вызов, который в обоих случаях лучше первого варианта. Для второго случая, чтобы вызвать первый вариант, нужно добавить к аргументу `const`, а для второго варианта — ничего. Поэтому второй побеждает. Если Вы определите свой объект так:

```
const std::string s("BBBBBBB");
```

То победит первый вариант.