# Parameter Pack + Rvalue Reference: что это такое, как работает и где об этом почитать?

Tags: c++

Пример:

```
template<typename... Type>
void function(Type&&... args)
{
    /* code */
}
```

Я знаю, что такое `parameter pack` и `rvalue reference`, и как они работают. Но я также знаю, что это не просто `parameter pack` + `rvalue reference`, и что `rvalue` здесь имеет совсем другой контекст. Но на `cppreference.com` или где-то ещё я не нашёл подробного объяснения того, почему и как это работает, и как это вообще называется. Буду признателен за информацию об этом незадокументированном "чуде", которое не так уж редко используется.

**PS: Нашёл кое-что интересное, прямо из 14го стандарта:**

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf

> Consider this code:

```
 void foo( X&& x );

 template<class Y>
 void bar( Y&& y );
```

> These parameters are fundamentally different.

Comment: Нет, при их использовании вместе никаких особенностей не добавляется. Может вы про forwarding-ссылки спрашиваете? Они могут использоваться как без паков, так и с ними. Это когда тип, на который ссылается rvalue-ссылка, является шаблонным параметром (или `auto`) и выводится компилятором автоматически.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, там Type&&... вроде как не является rvalue ссылкой, а заставляет Type повторять тип того, что передали в функцию. Но я не могу найти это в документации.

Comment: Нет, еще раз. То, что это parameter pack, просто позволяет передать любое количество аргументов, и все. Скорее всего вы спрашиваете про forwarding references, гуглите по этому названию.

Comment: Это не совсем rvalue reference, Скотт Майерс  называет это универсальной ссылкой, а вообще тут действуют правила сворачивания ссылок в зависимости от типа.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870438/215103) писал про forwarding ссылки, возможно поможет.

Comment: То, что вы процитировали, это не стандарт, а "proposal" - предложение об изменении стандарта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это *forwarding reference*. О них можно почитать [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) и [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call), т.е. вполне себе задокументировано. *Parameter pack* тут ни при чём, т.е. если вы напишите

```
template<typename T>
void function(T&& args)
{
    /* code */
}
```

то это тоже *forwarding reference*.

Используется, в основном, для идеальной передачи аргументов в функцию в связке с `std::forward`, которая тоже задокументирована [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). То есть если вы передаёте литерал `42`, то будет `int&&`, а если ссылку на целое, то будет `int&`. Иначе пришлось бы писать 2 перегрузки для обоих случаев.

Comment: На счёт примера, мне всё-таки кажется, что это будет как раз передача по ссылке для временных (rvalue) объектов, ну или для std::move(). Для конструкторов и для operator=() так и пишется (move construnctor и move assignment).

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον ну что я могу сказать, вам неправильно кажется :) Это *forwarding reference*, если бы там было `const T&&`, то другое дело. Для оператора присваивания и перемещающего конструктора пишется конкретный тип `A&&`, где `A` - название класса, а не `T&&`, где `T` - шаблонный параметр. Собственно, в документации, что я привёл, есть подобный пример, так что если мне не верите, почитайте там