# Что такое auto&&?

Tags: c++

Что такое `auto&&`? Как выводится тип такой переменной?

Comment: Это `forwarding reference`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870438/215103

Comment: @HolyBlackCat там нет `auto&&`

Comment: @ingeborga, вы знаете, что такое ключевое слово `auto`, а что такое`&&`?

Comment: @ingeborga Плохо читаете. :) *"По сути, "пробрасывающая ссылка" - это rvalue-ссылка (&&), но не на любой тип, а на ... Также ... подходит auto."* Но тот ответ рассчитан на то, читатель уже знает про обычные rvalue-ссылки. Сначала стоит почитать про них, а потом уже про forwarding-ссылки (в том ответе или где-то еще).

Answer (score 2):

`auto&&` **почти** всегда означает forwarding reference.

То есть вывод типа `auto&&` тут:

```
auto&& x = expression;
```

**почти** эквивалентен выводу типа `T&&` тут:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {}

foo(expression);
```

Исключение — список инициализации в фигурных скобках:

```
auto&& x = {1, 2, 3}; // OK
auto&& y{1, 2, 3}; // ERROR

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {}

foo({1, 2, 3}); // ERROR
foo(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3}); // OK
```

`auto&&` в параметре лямбды эквивалентно `T&&` без исключений.

Про forwarding reference чуть подробнее в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1156697/398802).

Comment: Интересно, что если написать `auto &&` в параметре лямбды/функции, то `foo({1,2,3})` работать не будет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat лямбды живут своей жизнью :) Например, без явного указания возвращаемого типа они могли выводить этот тип ещё в C++11, хотя `auto` в возвращаемом типе появился только в C++14

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda вот тут показано определение generic лямбды как шаблона, то есть `auto&&` у них своё,  именно эквивалентное `T&&`